# The bremsstrahlung and the atomic number of the element of the target

Tags: homework-and-exercises, x-rays

I came across this question in my text book, it says:

> What will happen to the x-rays if we change the element of the target in Coolidge tube by another one with a higher atomic number?

I believe that the characteristic spectrum will have a shorter wavelength, but I don't know whether the bremsstrahlung will be affected or not? And if the bremmstrahlung will undergo a change how would be this?
(Note: my book says the bremsstrahlung is affected by the voltage between the cathode and the anode and didn't mention anything about the element of the target material).

Comment: The wikipedia article covers this, perhaps in more depth than you might want.

Comment: You mean that article with the Köhn-Ebert formulas @JonCuster ? Basic answer is that the short-wave cutoff does not change. Intensity is a bit complicated, because self-absorption is also higher in high-Z materials.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As an example for X-ray crystallography, where targets of Molybdenum ($^{42}$Mo) are frequently used as "general workhorse", and Copper ($^{29}$Cu) is more suitable for organic matter, especially proteins, the superposition below may be helpful:

[image]

([source](http://www.xtal.iqfr.csic.es/Cristalografia/parte_02-en.html))

The then selected and used $K_\alpha$ are the at wavelengths of 0.709 (Mo) and 1.54 Å (Cu), respectively.

According to Pieter's comments, however, if the electrical potential is kept fixed, and only the target is exchanged, their short-wavelength cut-off will be the same:

[image]

([same source](http://www.xtal.iqfr.csic.es/Cristalografia/parte_02-en.html))

Comment: But in that figure, a higher voltage was used for the molybdenum anode (the short wavelength cut off is lower).

Comment: So there will be a change, right? Could you please explain it simply for me as I am just a high school student? And is there a change in the voltage for molybdenum as Pieter have already mentioned?

Comment: @Asmaa I still think the characteristic K\alpha lines will stay at their wavelength, altering electrical potential and current applied on the X-ray tube may influence if the process takes place and at what intensity (eventually how many X-ray photons are obtained).  But from Peter's two comments I extract that I was insofar wrong that 1) changing potential and current influences in any case the shape of spectral distribution of background / bremsstrahlung. And 2) keeping the two fixed while changing the target will yield a common cut-off at short wavelength' s side, regardless the target.